# Can Brasero damage my drive?

Tags: hardware, cd-drive, brasero

My CD/DVD burner failed after using Brasero to burn a CD (which failed).
I've ordered a new drive but was wondering could Brasero have caused the damage?

It was probably just a coincidence that my drive failed then but I want to be sure.

I've studied up on genisoimage and wodim and will use them instead in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more than unlikely that Brasero caused your drive to fail. Brasero cannot really cause hardware damage, and so if your drive is failing, it's likely that the hardware itself was already faulty or needed replacement.

Comment: Thanks Roland. Thought that was the case. It was an old drive and in my experience with second hand computers the optical drive is usually the first thing to go.